# How do I keep-alive tokio::TcpStream in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

The pseudo code is:

```
loop {
    let stream: tokio::TcpStream = accept_service.call().await;

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        http_service.call(stream).await();
    }
}
```

In `accept_service` I created a server socket(listener) using `socket2` create. `accept_service` returns an `AcceptFuture` with listener. In that execute `poll_accept()`, and get `tokio::TcpStream` as a result.

After get the stream, run several `middleware` for http processing, all of these actions are executed in a `task` created with `tokio::spawn`. That is, one client socket is executed in one `task`.
(`http_service` contains middleware services such as tls, http, proxy, accesslog and so on.)

All tcp and http settings related to keep-alive were applied.

#### Question

What I am curious about is how to enable http keep-alive by maintaining `tokio::TcpStream` even after the http response is finished.

I guess the `task` is terminated when the async operation for `http_request` is finished(all responses are sent out, and the `TcpStream` is also dropped and the connection is closed).

Should I keep the `TcpStream` as `Arc` so it doesn't drop when the task is finished?

If use `hyper`'s high-level API, I can easily implement keep-alive. But I used `socket2` and `tokio` tcp APIs to manage the connection directly. Are there any related APIs?

Answer (score 4):

For people coming here looking for an answer on how to set a keep alive on a `tokio::net::TcpStream`, or `std::net::TcpStream`:

You can wrap the stream in a `socket2::SocketRef`, this is what tokio does to set certain parameters on the socket (see `set_linger`) but it does not provide an api to set keep alive.

```rust
    let stream = TcpStream::connect(addr).await?;
    let sock_ref = socket2::SockRef::from(&stream);

    let mut ka = socket2::TcpKeepalive::new();
    ka = ka.with_time(Duration::from_secs(20));
    ka = ka.with_interval(Duration::from_secs(20));

    sock_ref.set_tcp_keepalive(&ka)?;

    // use `stream` as normal
```

Note this works with tokio 1.23.0 and socket2 0.4.7.